# how to add multiple pdfs to be converted into excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have program which converts pdf to excel, Now i want add multiple inputs i.e. multiple pdfs to be converted one by one.

my code is below:

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
import os
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import os

pdf = wi(filename= "pdfs/jaalna.pdf", resolution =300)
pdfImage = pdf.convert("jpg")

imageBlobs = []
for img in pdfImage.sequence:
    imgPage = wi(image = img)
    #img.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE )
    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpg'))
    recognized_text = []

for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
     im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
     text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng1+mar1')
     recognized_text.append(text)

newfile = open('aama.txt','w')
newfile.write(",".join(recognized_text))

#add a folder as input.
```

Comment: you can use `for name in ["pdfs/jaalna.pdf", "other/file.pdf"]:` to work with two files. Using `sys.argv` you can even run `script.py pdfs/jaalna.pdf other/file.pdf` and ` `for name in sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: since I am new to python can u show me example code? @furas

Comment: see code in answer below

Answer (score 0):

you can use loop

```
for name in ["pdfs/jaalna.pdf", "other/file.pdf"]:
    pdf = wi(filename=name, resolution=300)
    # rest of code
```

or you can use `sys.argv` to get names as

```
script.py pdfs/jaalna.pdf other/file.pdf other/third.pdf
```

and code

```
import sys

for name in sys.argv[1:]:
    pdf = wi(filename=name, resolution=300)
    # rest of code
```

Comment: thanks man its working But its overwriting the output..so i am getting only one output file :(

Comment: use mode "a" (append) instead of "w" (write). Or open it only once - before `for name`

Comment: its not happening,i am using pandas to write into excel..its throwing me an error. :(

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page - you will have more space for code and error message. In current question you don't use `pandas` to write in excel format (ie. xlsx) - you only write in .txt but you use standard `open().write()`

Comment: i cant ask more questions on stack.

Comment: these are some last lines of my code.                                                              out_fl = open('cleaned_jaalna_1.txt','r')
  os.remove('pdf_line_content.txt')

  df = pd.DataFrame(row, columns = ['नाव', 'Guardian', 'वय & लिंग',
          'घर क्रमांक','Unique ID'])

  for colmn in df.columns:
   df[colmn] = df[colmn].apply(lambda i: ','.join(i)) 

  df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
  df.dropna(how = 'all', inplace=True)

  writer = pd.ExcelWriter('yeniye.xlsx')
  df.to_excel(writer,'Content')

  writer.save()

Comment: what error do you have? Doc for [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter)

Comment: i dont get any error, i just get only one output. It overwrites the first one.

Comment: as I said before - you have to use mode "a" to append. ExcelWriter also has "mode" - see documentation. Or you may have to load all data to memory, add elements in memory and save all data back to file.

Comment: when I use mode = append then it is writing data to existing file,not creating new file :(

Comment: I don't know if I understand you. So you want create new file 'yeniye.xlsx' at start,  append all data to this file ? And when you will run script againt then it has to delete 'yeniye.xlsx', create new 'yeniye.xlsx' and append all data to this file ?  You can delete 'yeniye.xlsx' at start using `os.remove('yeniye.xlsx')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. This will loop through every PDF file in the folder directory you define. Be sure to update your file_path to be where your PDFs are saved, making sure you use double backslashs in place of single backslashes.

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import os

file_path = "C:\\Users\\..."

for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf = wi(file, resolution =300)
        pdfImage = pdf.convert("jpg")

        imageBlobs = []
        for img in pdfImage.sequence:
            imgPage = wi(image = img)
            #img.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE )
            imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpg'))
            recognized_text = []

        for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
             im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
             text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng1+mar1')
             recognized_text.append(text)

        newfile = open(file+'.txt','w')
        newfile.write(",".join(recognized_text))

        #add a folder as input.
```